# How to run multiple SQL script files in a Shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, sql-scripts

I have to create 1 UNIX Shell script. In that shell script i want to run multiple SQL script files from the same directory. I have used like this-

```
#!usr/bin/ksh
SQLPATH = /usr/sql/
(cd $SQLPATH;
'sqlplus usr/password@sid <<EOF
 spool <db_file>.log
 @<db_name>.sql
 set echo off
 set heading off
 spool off
 &&

 spool <db_file2>.log
 @<db_name2>.sql
 set echo off
 set heading off
 spool off
 &&

 spool <db_file3>.log
 @<db_name3>.sql
 set echo off
 set heading off
 spool off
 exit;
 EOF')

exit 0
```

There are multiple SQL scripts like this and for each SQL script I have to create log files so I used `spool` here. After every SQL script files execute 
I used `&&`. So Is it good to use `&&` here and in 3rd line `;` when I define the **PATH**. Please provide me the better solution.

Comment: What's with the single quotes? (And similarly, spaces aren't allowed around the `=` in a variable assignment, and `EOF` ending a heredoc isn't allowed to be indented). I can't see how your code would ever work as currently written.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually there are around 20 SQL script files which is 3-4 different locations path so frequently path used in the shell script I declare variable here. That's why i used `cd` here. Also after `EOF` what is the use of `&&` which is mentioned in the answer.

Comment: `foo && bar` is shorthand for `if foo; then bar; fi` i.e. run `bar` only iff `foo` completed successfully. I thought that's what you tried to ask about -- what do you want the `&&` to mean in your own code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't override the system `PATH` (or now `SQLPATH`) and don't put commands in single quotes.  Use lowercase for your private variables, and you can't have spaces around the equals sign in an assignment; but a variable you only use once is useless anyway, so I took it out, and hardcoded the `cd` argument.

I'm guessing you want something like

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

# No spaces around equals sign, and don't use uppercase for private variables
# But why use a variable at all anyway
#sqlpath=/usr/sql
cd /usr/sql  # is this really necessary and useful??

sqlplus usr/password@sid <<____EOF &&
 spool <db_file>.log
 @<db_name>.sql
 set echo off
 set heading off
 spool off
____EOF

sqlplus usr/password@sid <<____EOF &&
 spool <db_file2>.log
 @<db_name2>.sql
 set echo off
 set heading off
 spool off
____EOF

sqlplus usr/password@sid <<____EOF
 spool <db_file3>.log
 @<db_name3>.sql
 set echo off
 set heading off
 spool off
____EOF

# exit 0  # Not necessary or useful
```

If the multiple `sqlplus` commands can be executed in a single session, that would be an obvious improvement; but I'm guessing `sqlplus` has no way of expressing what you appear to mean with `&&` (this syntax seems to have a [quite distinct meaning in `sqlplus`](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/sub-var2-099853.html)).

Comment: can i use `cd /usr/sql` directly without use `()` and what is meaning of ____ before `EOF`. To run every SQL script file I have to connect every time DB through `sqlplus` or only one time and then run all the SQL scripts. Could you please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: The parentheses create a subshell but the entire script already runs in its own shell instance, so the subshell does nothing useful. You probably don't need to `cd` at all (do you have write access to this directory?). The underscores are just for legibility -- the token after `<<` can be any text.  I don't understand your last sentence but it seems to chime with the last paragraph in this answer.

Comment: when i run the above shell script then it is showing an error. `-ksh: <file_name>.ksh: not found [No such file or directory]`

Comment: @ShahinP The problem is not with the script, but with how you are running it. I can't tell you what's wrong because you have replaced the real thing with `<file_name>` but perhaps you are looking for `./<file_name>.ksh`

Comment: I have run from 2 type `./<file_name>.ksh` and `ksh <file_name>.ksh` but in both time it is showing the same error

Comment: I noticed a typo but I don't think it affects this script. What happens if you do `sh ./<file_name>.ksh`?

Comment: Yes i have run this script by using `./` but i am getting error. I don't know why. There s any need to mention ORACLE_HOME path & anything else

Comment: Notice how I put `sh` instead of `ksh`? Can you try that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188879/discussion-between-tripleee-and-shahin-p).

Answer (score 1):

Make a function

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
SQLPATH=/usr/sql # Offtopic: Better use lowercase for your own variables

process_sql_and_log() {
   if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
      echo "Usage: $0 sqlfile logfile"
      return 1
   fi
   sqlplus usr/password@sid <<EOF
spool ${2}
@${1}
set echo off
set heading off
spool off
exit;
EOF
}

  cd "${SQLPATH}" &&
  process_sql_and_log db_name.sql  db_file.log  &&
  process_sql_and_log db_name2.sql db_file2.log &&
  process_sql_and_log db_name3.sql db_file3.log

exit 0
```